# Generate custom campaign parameters for your advertising URLs

Tags: url, gwt

I have little problem, I tried to generate google  custom campaign parameters for   advertising URLs with  [this google tool](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en), but my url looks like this:
 `http://www.example.com/servis.php#!servis-xxx-yyy-zzz`,
but this tool doesnt consider my url as valid.
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?
thanks